# Unable to do event handling using Jquery on API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myBtn").on("click",function(){
        alert('myBtn Clicked');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn">Sample</button>    
</body>
</html>
```

For the above mentioned code click event is not firing. I used JSFiddle it works fine.
It works fine in case of delegation. The code I used for delegation is below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click","button",function(){
        alert('myBtn Clicked');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn">Sample</button>    
</body>
```

Help me in solving this....

Comment: set a `$(document).ready(function() { content... });`

Comment: Please read the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery). It explains how to use jQuery properly, in particular: *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready."*  It works in jsFiddle because the default setting is to run code `onLoad`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

So for you it would be:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myBtn").on("click",function(){
        alert('myBtn Clicked');
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your code inside document.ready()

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").on("click",function(){
        alert('myBtn Clicked');
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn">Sample</button>    
</body>
</html>
```

Now in second case your code worked because document is loaded first in the page and attaching may be done to it without document.ready but at that time html element may be loading so event can't be attached to them

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it on Initiliaze function. Maybe javascript of jquery is not loaded

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click","button',function(){  
            alert('myBtn Clicked');  
        });  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples: your DOM isn't loaded yet when you are adding the listeners! Make sure the DOM is loaded first by either

- use the `ready` event
- move the script tag to the end of your body

---

```
$( document ).ready(function(e) {
    // add listeners here
});
```